# "value error: shape mismatch" but data same size same type

Tags: python, plot

I am trying to plot using scatter3D and receive the error above. When I query my x,y and z arguments they are each lists of floats and each have the same number of values? The code is:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
xs = coords_x
ys = coords_y
zs = test
ax.scatter3D(xs,ys,zs, color = 'green')
plt.show()
```

and when I check len() and type() of each variable I get the same number and type. This is my first stackoverflow question...be nice

Comment: You are saying the shapes are the same, python is saying they are not. My money is on python, but without actual reproducible code, it's impossible for us to know what is wrong. Note, asking the length of an array is not the same as asking the shape. Are you sure all these are one-dimensional?

Comment: Welcome! Just a guess here, but how about just `ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, color='green')`? My understanding is that after adding a subplot with the `projection='3d'` argument, you can call `ax.scatter` with three data series and it should just work, based on https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html

Comment: Mark: thanks, I think betting on python is wise. The code won't really have the answer (because it reads the x ,y data in from a json; and reads the z data in from a csv file). In each case the data gets written into lists (based on your comment I tried testing its shape and returned "list objects" have no shape attribute. I printed the lists and they are  indeed 1 dimensional. Any other thoughts? Copying the code in case it helps:

Comment: coords_x = []
coords_y = []
json_file = 'L.json'
  
with open(json_file) as jFile:
    data = json.load(jFile)
    ind = 0

    for face in data["Faces"]:
        coords_x.append(data["Faces"][ind]["center"][0])
        coords_y.append(data["Faces"][ind]["center"][1])
        ind += 1

with open('voltage_final__0.txt') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    result = []
    test =[]

    for row in csv_reader:
        result = row 
        for i in result:
            test.append(float(i))

Comment: @Peter Leimbigler, thanks for your comment. I tried using just 'ax.scatter' but got the same error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question instead of adding comments; code is unreadable in comments (especially Python, where whitespace matters!).